# Excel Formula...Complex...Invoice tracking without inputting info into multiple spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have a list of store# in one worksheet(1) and another worksheet which has (2)invoice tracking for these stores. As the store# & invoice # are added to one worksheet(2), I want the invoice number to insert into worksheet (1) which has a the list of store# next to the correct store number. So, if I input Inv. 3124 (column1) for Store 4545 (column2) into the worksheet (2), I would like it to find store 4545 in worksheet1 and put the invoice # next to that corresponding store.

I am trying to find an easy way to track invoicing by the store number...ensuring each store is only billed once but I want to minimize the amount of time I am spending inputting information into an spreadsheets.

Thanks!

Comment: Using Pivot table you can view the store number with invoice number in the format you want. Worksheet(1) basically presents the data format you want and does not have a function - is that correct?. Update your question with a image of worksheet (2) - let us see if pivot table would work or not

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [pivot table](https://support.office.com/client/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)!<sup>1</sup>

So if you have your data in a table you can use a pivot table. I'll assume for this exercise that your table looks like this -

[image]

If you highlight the table and go to **insert - pivot table** so that the range is the table and it goes to a new worksheet, you can set up a pivot table.

[image]

Here are two examples using different metrics (pictured)-

The amount of each invoice for each store, you can see if any invoices are listed twice or charged to two stores: [link to bigger view of picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFTCz.png)

[image]

Here is matching the store to the invoice and counting how many times that invoice appears for the store. It also gives you a total count of invoices per store: [link to bigger view of picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndf8e.png)

[image]

You can do any number of configurations with the pivot table, [take a look at all the reference material from Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Create-a-PivotTable-from-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).

<sup>1</sup>*this is another installment of the "[sounds](https://superuser.com/questions/817081/count-row-and-column-in-pivot-table/817137#817137) [like](https://superuser.com/questions/733347/excel-combine-rows-dollar-amount-with-matching-row-values/733358#733358) [a](https://superuser.com/questions/703119/count-first-occurrence-of-one-criterion-based-on-a-second-criterion/703134#703134) [job](https://superuser.com/questions/703732/finding-a-unique-value-in-excel/703871#703871) [for](https://superuser.com/questions/740598/excel-2010-pivot-formatting-cant-indent-and-wrap-fields/741977#741977) [pivot](https://superuser.com/questions/749247/excel-sumproduct-sumif/749280#749280) [table](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pivot-table)" [series](https://superuser.com/users/116196/raystafarian)*